# Is the SkyRC B6 Nano charger suitable for charging single 18650's from 2.4v-2.6v

Tags: battery-charging, charger, charging, low-battery

I have salvaged six 18650's from a laptop we've owned for years.  Battery voltage: four of them are ~2.63v, two are ~2.46v

I have a SkyRC B6 Nano charger (https://www.skyrc.com/Charger/B6nano).  I've wired up a single 18650 cell holder to an XT60, plugged it into the Nano's output socket.

But it doesn't want to charge them - it returns error code 2 (cell number is wrong).

I'm using the correct mode for Lithium Ion; "charge" option (i.e. not "balance charge"); set to "1" cell; I've tried various current strengths including 0.3A and 0.1A.

Is it possible to use this charger (am I doing it wrong), or will I need to try something else?

Normally I use this charger for balance charging a 5C 18650 battery pack (with an additional balance lead).

Comment: As far as I know, 2.5V is *critically* low for lithium batteries. But maybe there are different kinds of lithium ion. They probably should not be charged.

Comment: They're dead, Jim.  Those chargers won't charge lithiums below about 3 volts.  If you are intent on using them, charge them as NiMh at low rates (100ma) until the cell voltage hits 3.1v, then charge them as LiIon.  You risk fire though.

Comment: B6 Nano - tiny charger, needs 380W power supply!!!

Comment: @BryanBoettcher set charge time and capacity limit to low value and fire risk is very low.